# IIS rewrite .jpg to .ashx

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to use the IIS rewrite module to rewrite:

https://www.xxxmydomainxxx.com/image.jpg?vehicle=hyundai-tucson-diesel-estate-17-crdi-blue-drive-se-nav-5dr-2wd&capid=71703&width=510&height=340&type=car&source=caranddriving

to

https://www.xxxmydomainxxx.com/image.ashx?vehicle=hyundai-tucson-diesel-estate-17-crdi-blue-drive-se-nav-5dr-2wd&capid=71703&width=510&height=340&type=car&source=caranddriving

Basically convert image.jpg to image.ashx

I've got a wildcard pattern like this:

https://www.xxxmydomainxxx.com/image.jpg*

rewrite to:

https://www.xxxmydomainxxx.com/image.ashx{R:1}

When I test the pattern in IIS it seems to work fine, but live it just returns a 404.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at what the result of the rewrite is?

Comment: change the rewrite rule to redirect, then you will be able to check the rewrite results easily. and query string is not a part of path so it will not be matched with your *,  you should use “pass query string” property in the rule

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite should be:

```
<rule name="image.jpg rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^image.jpg$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/image.ashx" />
</rule>
```

This part `^image.jpg$` will match all requests to image.jpg only

This part `<action type="Rewrite" url="/image.ashx" />` will rewrite it to image.ashx.

You don't need to use `{R:1}` because by default rewrite module is appending all query strings to rewrites by default.